# SQL injection via LINKS?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

its about editing two fields in my database table (note_name and note_description) and i take some info from the link and the new field from a form like this :

LINK :

```
/main_edit.php?edit=note_name2&type=PHP
```

AND :

```
elseif(isset($_GET['edit'])){
        $note_type=$_GET['type'];
        $old_note_name=$_GET['edit'];
        $new_note_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_note_name']);
        $new_note_description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['new_note_description']);
        $query="UPDATE functions
                SET note_name='{$new_note_name}', 
                note_description='{$new_note_description}'
                WHERE note_name='{$old_note_name}'
                ";
      $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);}
```

is SQL injection via The link is possible here and if yes how to protect from it ?

thank You !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes - you aren't escaping `$old_note_name` for some reason, and with it being at the end of the query it is the most vulnerable variable. You appear to know what to do... use `mysql_real_escape_string` on that variable just like you have on the others.

Otherwise, this is all it would take:
`/main_edit.php?type=PHP&edit=note_name2';drop table functions;#`

Comment: Fyi: typically, one leaves a comment when down voting so that the answerer may improve their answer. A down vote without a comment is meaningless.

Answer (score 4):

you can use prepared statements, something like:

```
$query = "UPDATE functions SET note_name=?, note_description=? WHERE note_name=?"; 
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('sss', $new_note_name, $new_note_description, $old_note_name);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: I'd +1000 this if I could. Stop concatenating string to makes SQL queries, use prepared statements people.

Comment: You can't trust any input in your php script, because malicious people can just write their own html and submit anything they want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes cause you're not escaping `$_GET['edit']` .. what about to try this:

```
$old_note_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['edit']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this :-

```
$old_note_name=$_GET['edit'];
```

To

```
$old_note_name= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['edit'], $connection);
```

And apply $connection to all call to function mysql_real_escape_string

Lastly, take a look on [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)